# How to introduce loop numeration into a formula in order to skip columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formula, bloomberg

I'm a beginner with Vba. I have the following code:

```
Sub addbdh()
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

n = Selection.Count

For i = 1 To n
Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).Formula = "=BDH(B" & i * 2 - 1 & ",A1 ,B1 ,Today())"
Next i
End Sub
```

Initally it was aimed to introduce a formula in columns of 3rd row but skipping one column in the middle each time the loop rounds.

Neverthless, I realized my code works for the concept just described but transposed (skipping rows to introduce the formula in the rows of B column).

Since columns are named with alphabet letters, I don't know how can I introduce in a loop within a formula en element to skip columns as I've done at first with rows in the instruction:

`Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).Formula = "=BDH(B" & i * 2 - 1 & ",A1 ,B1 ,Today())"`

More specifically, I don't know how to convert `"=BDH(B" & i * 2 - 1 & ",A1 ,B1 ,Today())"` in order to skip one column each time instead of one row.

Could Someone help me?

Lot of thanks

Comment: Use `Step = 3` after `For i = 1 to n` to make something on every 3rd value of i.

Comment: The problem is that i is an element defined as an integer, and since the Excel columns are named with the alphabet letters, it is not useful if I want to skip columns, notice that my loop is based in the name of each cell I want to apply the loop, the problem is how to change the name of each cell to skip a column every time the loop rounds.

Comment: Use Cells(row,column) to define the cell, where both row and column are an integer.

Comment: Check my last comment, I have just edited

Comment: please provide an example of the desired results, as your discription of them is vague.

Comment: You can use R1C1 formula style ;), something like `Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=BDH(RC" & i * 2 - 1 & ",R1C1 ,R1C2 ,Today())"`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Put it as a repply so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using indexed values in formulas, it is sometimes easier to use R1C1 formula style than A1 style.

In your case, your R1C1 formula could be:

```
Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=BDH(RC" & i * 2 - 1 & ",R1C1 ,R1C2 ,Today())"
```

which means for the first parameter "cell in the same row as the current cell, (2*i-1)th column ", for the second one "cell in row 1 column 1 (aka A1)" and for the last "cell in row 1 column 2 (aka B1)".

Comment: It's OK but I had to add a 1 after the first R in the RC of the formula, like this: 

`Cells(3, i * 2 - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=BDH(R1C" & i * 2 - 1 & ",R1C1 ,R1C2 ,Today())"'`